# How to redirect to landing page if "Subscription" is acknowledged in Android

Tags: android, subscription, in-app-subscription, in-app

```
if(!purchase.isAcknowledged()){
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                        .build();
                billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams,acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
                binding.tvSubsts.setText("Subscribed");
                isSuccess=true;
```

When subscription payment is successful it will redirect to the landing page which is the contents of the application, whether in ListView or BottomView.

Comment: At first, please use the {Code} formatting in your question for easier visibility. Next we need more Information on your setup. Do you want to transition to another Activity or is it another Fragment? Can you please provide a bit more sample code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TIMBLOCKER Yes, a transition to another Activity

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your Code as follows:

```
if(!purchase.isAcknowledged()){
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams,acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            binding.tvSubsts.setText("Subscribed");
            isSuccess=true;

            //Transition to your Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);

            //pass data if needed
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);

            startActivity(intent);}
```

In your DestinationActivity you can do the following to recieve the Information:

```
String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Here you can show all details that the Subsciption in `AcknowledgePurchaseParams` has to the user.

Comment: TIMBLOCKER, these codes work:  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class); startActivity(intent);}. The funny thing is I don't know how to implement this code: intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId); . Need help, thank you

Comment: Do you even want to pass Data to the other Activity? If you do not want to pass any data, you can just delete this line. When using the bundle you have a Key-Value Store. In the example I'm using a Key called EXTRA_SESSION_ID to this key you can add any String value. In the Other Activity you can retrieve the Value when Passing the key in the other activity. But you dont have to. Hope that help and the answer gets accepted ;)